# Converting an old asp.net 1.0 to newer version, web.config changes?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

When convering a asp.net 1.0 app to run with asp.net 3.5 vs.net 2008, do I need to modify the web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio should do the conversion for you. If there are  errors you will see them in the error report. Unfortunately you'll have to manually fixes the errors.

The web.config shouldn't having any compatibility issues. Visual Studio will add the new web.config entries for you.

If you are lucky it your applications should seamlessly upgrade. Most applications that I upgraded started ran after the conversion.